# Vector out of Bounds error on one computer but not another (Architecture problem?)

Tags: c++, vector, overflow, cpu-architecture

I have had problems compiling code on different computers but normally on runtime they behave the same, this problem however I can not wrap my head around.

I have been able to locate the exact method where the problem exists which ill post below, I can also post other relevant code but the entire project is several hundred lines.

```
void Algos::addTasksToQueue(unsigned &indexOfNextTask, const vector<Task> &taskPool){
    while(this->getClockCount() >= taskPool[indexOfNextTask].getArrivalTime() && indexOfNextTask < taskPool.size()){
       this->addToQueue(taskPool[indexOfNextTask]);
       ++indexOfNextTask;
     }

}
```

I am compiling with C++14

On my personal MacBook this runs no problem, however on the university system a runtime error occurs

```
/usr/include/c++/10/debug/vector:434:
In function:
std::__debug::vector<_Tp, _Allocator>::const_reference 
std::__debug::vector<_Tp, 
_Allocator>::operator[](std::__debug::vector<_Tp, 
_Allocator>::size_type) const [with _Tp = Task; _Allocator = 
std::allocator<Task>; std::__debug::vector<_Tp, 
_Allocator>::const_reference = const Task&; std::__debug::vector<_Tp, 
_Allocator>::size_type = long unsigned int]

Error: attempt to subscript container with out-of-bounds index 10, but 
container only holds 10 elements.

Objects involved in the operation:
sequence "this" @ 0x0x7ffcbf845150 {
  type = std::__debug::vector<Task, std::allocator<Task> >;
}
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Changing the code to say indexOfNextTask < taskPool.size()-1 runs on the university system however the output at the end is wrong because the while loop terminates one line too many.

I have done out statements in the while loop ending with a buffer refresh (endl) and NEVER is the number indexOfNextTask equal to 10.

Comment: The method add to queue is a just a simple
void Algos::addToQueue(const Task newTask){
 this->queue.push_back(newTask);
}

Comment: It could be out of bounds in both but not show any kind of error.

Comment: You should rearrange the conditional such that `indexOfNextTask < taskPool.size()` is first. I mean `while( indexOfNextTask < taskPool.size() && this->getClockCount() >= taskPool[indexOfNextTask].getArrivalTime())`

Comment: Let me know if this makes any sense @drescherjm
Removing the CXX flag  -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG on the university computer makefile and now it runs with no exception??
But with that flag on my computer it still runs

Comment: Undefined behavior caused by an out of bounds access is not required to cause a crash. So you could have a silent error.